# gdal_translate() function in R not working, but no error message

Tags: r, gdal, file-conversion, rgdal, geotiff

I am using the gdal_translate function in R to convert an image in JPEG2000 format to GeoTIFF.

My script works on my own laptop, however when I try to run it on a different laptop it is not working. R is busy without producing an output and without giving an error message, just nothing happens.

my script:

```
input <- "myDir/myImage.jp2"
output <- "myDir/myImageOutput.tiff"
gdal_translate(input, output, overwrite=T)
```

Once I got the error message that GDAL does not exist, however I have installed, and re-installed all packages, checked in the win-library that the packages exists. I have run all the libraries that I have on my own laptop where it works. I have even re-installed R in the exact version as is on my own laptop (v. 3.4.1)

Anyone who has experienced this or know the issue?

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> This function assumes the user has a working GDAL on their system.  If the "gdalUtils_gdalPath" option has been set (usually by gdal_setInstallation), the GDAL found in that path will be used. If nothing is found, gdal_setInstallation will be executed to attempt to find a working GDAL that has the right drivers as specified with the "of" (output format) parameter.

For example, my laptop does not have a working GDAL.

When I run

```
gdalUtils::gdal_translate()
```

the hard drive grinds away for quite a while until eventually returning `NULL` and warning me about not being able to find a working GDAL.

This is not an `R` problem. The problem is the lack of a GDAL on my laptop. This is likely your problem on this other laptop you are using (or, that `gdal_setInstallation` can't find it.) So make sure this other laptop has a GDAL and/or set it explicitly.